# How to compare the two columns of two DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 `DatagridView` and I have same column in `datagridView1` and `dataGridView2` now I want to compare each rows `Column [ID]` in `datagridView` 1 and 2, if that `ID` exist in 2 Columns, the `Column["Names"]` and `["Age"]` of `datagridView2` pass to `dataGridView1`.

This is only I have, but it didn't showing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; a++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[a].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[a].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            i++;
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *didn't showing* mean?  Why are you incrementing the indexers inside the loop?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: For the sake of everybody, starting with you, do get the formatting right! - Aslo: What do you want to do when the fields match???

Comment: @Taw if the field match it will pass the column[Name] and [Age] of datagridView2 to datagridView 1.

Comment: @Plutonix i just want to check if datagridView1 Column[ID] has match in dataGridView2 Column[ID] if they have match fields it will pass  the Empty Column [Name] and [Age] of datagridView2 to dataGridView1

Comment: You might want to update the question accordingly so anyone still interested can understand what you are after

Comment: We do not know if you have bound your data from somewhere. We do not know your columns. What is the problem? Makes difficult to help. Looks a bit like you are doing a kind of join on two tables. Perhaps if you open more why you are doing this, you could find out there is some completely different way to achieve what you want. If this is what you need, the nested loop is very inefficient if you have a lot of rows. It is better to put the source table into a hash table first and then loop through the target table filling it in. You can get O(n) instead of O(n^2) when hash operations are O(1).

Comment: OK, but why increase the loop counters? This will skip each row after a hit is found!